# Can action creators from createAsyncThunk be added to 'reducers' instead of 'extraReducers' in createSlice?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In the [Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-createasyncthunk), reducers for the action creators returned by `createAsyncThunk` are passed as `extraReducers` to `createSlice`, like so:

```js
export const fetchTodos = createAsyncThunk('todos/fetchTodos', async () => {
  // async logic
})

const todosSlice = createSlice({
  // omit unnecessary code
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchTodos.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'loading'
      })
  }
})
```

Can the action creators be added to `reducers` instead? For example:

```js
//omit createAsyncThunk

const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // omit reducer cases
    fetchTodos.fulfilled = (state, action) => {
      // some code to update state based on action.payload
  }
})
```

The docs say

> We can't handle those inside of the createSlice.reducers field, because those generate new action types too.

Why is this the case?

Comment: The `reducers` property creates an action and responds to it.  You use `extraReducers` when you are responding to an action which already exists.

Comment: So it is just a semantic difference, but in theory adding to either `reducers` or `extraReducers` should both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't be.

The `reducers` field is used to define case reducers, *and generate new action types that correspond to those reducers*, which will be namespaced to the slice's `name`.  In other words, it's used to help define new action types inside of the slice itself.

The `extraReducers` is used to define case reducers that will run in response to *other actions defined outside of the slice*.

`createAsyncThunk` defines new action types, and those will be defined outside of the slice. So, a slice must use `extraReducers` to handle those actions.

If the action creators from `createAsyncThunk` are added in `reducers` as a computed key name, this will end up creating duplicate action types that combine the slice `name` prefix *and* the thunk's action type strings.  That means that when the thunk dispatches its actions, they won't match the types that the slice is looking for, and the reducer will never run.

Comment: Why can't the new action types from `createAsyncThunk` be dispatched to, and run in `reducers` though? Is it just because `createSlice` already namespaces reducers with its name?

Comment: Correct. If you were to try to pass a `createAsyncThunk`-generated action type as a computed key name in the `reducers` object, you would end up generating a _new_ action type that is not the same thing, which is doubly wrong. The slice would never respond to the thunk-dispatched action.